# GoogleCloud Storage - Delete file?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I can see [a sample](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-cloud-storage) of uploading a file to the Google Cloud storage. I, however, can't find a sample of deleting a file in the cloud storage. Does deleting a file API exist?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the delete API documentation for the JSON API: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/delete

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete_blob(bucket_name, destination_blob_name):
"""Deletes a blob from the bucket."""
try:
    storage_client = storage.Client(project = project)
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.delete()
    log.info('Blob {} deleted.'.format(destination_blob_name))
except Exception as e:
    pass
```